# every sequence in a compact subspace $K$ has a point of accumulation in $K$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $V$ be a complex vector space with a norm $\|\cdot \|$ and $K$ a compact subspace of $V$. Show: Every sequence $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $K$ has an point of accumulation in $K$.

Comment: I give you one book that has this answer: Aliprantis chapter one ..section compact space and compact function

Comment: Note to those who could be confused, like me: accumulation point means cluster point, ie limit of a convergent subsequence. And this does not mean limit point of the set consisting of the values of the sequence. In some places, this is what is meant by accumulation point of a sequence...

Comment: By Bolzano-Weierstrass, every sequence in a compact subset $K$ of a metric space admits a converging subsequence in $K$. Since we are in a metric space where topology is sequential, limits of subsequences are are precisely the cluster points=accumulation points of the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

One of the definitione of a compact set K is that every sequence in it has a convergent subsequence. So you need to take the limit of that subsequence, which is a accumulation point of the subsequence and the set also.
This transforms straigthforward into subspace, because a compact subspace K in X is a compact set K in X.